# 2 variable induction proof divisibility

Tags: number-theory, induction, divisibility

> Prove that $$a^{2^n}-1$$ is divisible by $4 \times 2^n$ for all odd integers $a$ and for all integers $n$.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to solve this when theres 2 variables involved in the induction. Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Fix any odd $a$, i.e., let $a  =2k+1$ for some integer $k$, and induct on $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\;a^{2^n}-1=a^{2 \cdot 2^{n-1}}-1=\left(a^{2^{n-1}}\right)^2-1=\left(a^{2^{n-1}}-1\right)\left(a^{2^{n-1}}+1\right)\,$, where the first factor is divisible by $\,4 \cdot 2^{n-1}\,$ by the induction hypothesis on $\,n\,$, and the second one is even.

Comment: Is locking a value as a required for this?

Comment: @JeffreyChiu What do you mean by `locking a value`? The above uses that $a$ is odd to determine that the second factor is even, but does not otherwise `lock` its value in any way - $a$ can still be *any* odd number.

Comment: I'm probably wrong on this but our base case involved 2 variables then a = 1 and n = 1?

Comment: @JeffreyChiu Since the induction in my answer is on $n$ alone, the base case is just $n=1$ for an arbitrary odd $a$. You can prove *that* base case by induction on $a$ if you really want to, but that follows a lot more directly from $a^2-1=(a-1)(a+1)$ being the product of two consecutive even numbers, one of which must be a multiple of $4$.

Answer (score 0):

$$a^{2^n}-1=(a^2-1)(a^2+1)(a^4+1)...(a^{2^{n-1}}+1)$$it is obvious that $a^{2^k}+1$ is divisible by $2$ and there are $n-1$ of them. Also the square of every odd integer is of form $8q+1$ implying that $a^2-1$ is divisible by $8$ therefore whole the multiplication is divisible by $8\cdot 2^{n-1}=4\cdot 2^n$